# Alternate translation for: “Every real number except zero has a multiplicative inverse.”

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

A given text states, “Every real number except zero has a multiplicative inverse" (where mul-
tiplicative inverse of a real number x is a real number y such that xy = 1).

It offers the following translation:

$$\forall x((x\neq 0) \rightarrow \exists y(xy = 1)).$$

I personally translated the statement as:

$$\forall x \exists y((x\neq 0)\rightarrow (xy = 1)).$$

Are these two statements logically equivalent?
My reasoning being, for every real number x, there exists a real number y, such that if x does not equal zero, then the product of x and y equals 1.

Comment: Yes, these are equivalent. The implication from bottom to top is the easy one. For the other one, given $x$ you have to pick some $y$. If $x\neq 0$, pick the $y$ given by the hypothesis. If $x=0$, you can choose $y$ to be what you want, since $x=0$ the proposition will still be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes :

> $∀x((x \ne 0 ) → ∃y(xy = 1 ))$

and

> $∀x∃y((x \ne 0) → (xy = 1))$

are logically equivalent, because :

> > $\vdash \exists y (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \leftrightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \exists y \beta) \quad $ if $y$ is not *free* in $\alpha$.

In your case, $\alpha$ is $(x \ne 0 )$ and $y$ is not *free* in it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a general principle that if $y$ does not appear in $\varphi$, then the following are equivalent.

1. $\varphi \rightarrow \exists y(\psi)$
2. $\exists y(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$

Comment: (1) -> (2) only works in classical logic, right? Because in my head I'd first do or-elimination on $\varphi \vee \neg \varphi$. In the first case, I have $\exists y.\ \psi$ per (1), in the second case, I just pick an arbitrary $y$.

Comment: @ComFreek, sorry I'm not sure. You're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.
This principle is known as "null quantification rule".
In this case, the left-hand $x$ is independent of domain $y$. So, we can place $y$ domain on left hand side.
Follow the below link to get more details about null quantification rule. 
 https://gateoverflow.in/130504/null-qunatification-rule